# How can I make the `cv2.imshow` output the same as the `plt.imshow` output?

Tags: image, opencv, matplotlib

How can I make the `cv2.imshow` output the same as the `plt.imshow` output?

```
# loading image
img0 = cv2.imread("image.png")
# converting to gray scale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# remove noise
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)

# convolute with proper kernels
laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img, cv2.CV_64F)
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=5)  # x
sobely = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=5)  # y
imgboth = cv2.addWeighted(sobelx, 0.5, sobely, 0.5, 0)

plt.imshow(imgboth, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

cv2.imshow("img", cv2.resize(imgboth, (960, 540)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

original image

[image]

```
plt.output
```

[image]

```
cv2.imshow
```

[image]

Comment: work with floats, scale the values, then add 0.5 so 0 becomes gray. I'll make an answer of it if you want.

Comment: Yes please. Can you add a working answer? @Christopher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
# ...
canvas = imgboth.astype(np.float32)
canvas /= np.abs(imgboth).max()
canvas += 0.5
cv.namedWindow("canvas", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.imshow("canvas", canvas)
cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyWindow("canvas")
```

[image: canvas]

only looks different because you posted thumbnails, not the original size image.

when you give `imshow` floating point values, which you do because `laplacian` and `sobelx` are floating point, then it assumes a range of `0.0` .. `1.0` as black .. white.

matplotlib automatically scales data. OpenCV's imshow doesn't. both behaviors have pros and cons.